# Prove that $\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{t^{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + t^2}} dt = \mathcal{O}(R^{\epsilon}) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to prove that $$\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{t^{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + t^2}} dt = \mathcal{O}(R^{\epsilon}) $$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $R >0$.

It is very easy to see for the case when $\epsilon \geq 1$ because
$$\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{t^{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + t^2}} dt \leq \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{t^{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{t^2}} dt \leq \int_{-R}^{R} t^{\epsilon-1} dt = \mathcal{O}(R^{\epsilon})  $$

but the above argument does not hold for the case when $0 < \epsilon < 1$. How can I prove this when $0 < \epsilon < 1$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. If you edit into your question the "very easy" argument for $\epsilon\ge1$ with an explanation of how it relies on that assumption, maybe we can suggest how to generalize.

Comment: How about dividing the interval by $|t|\le 1$ and $1<|t|\le R$?

Comment: What is $t^\varepsilon$ for $-R<t<0$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not clear what is $t^{\varepsilon}$ if $t\in(-R,0)$, as already observed by Gary. However, observe that $$\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^{2}}}=\text{arcsinh}\left(2t\right)+C$$ hence $$\int_{0}^{R}\frac{t^{\varepsilon}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^{2}}}dt=\frac{1}{2^{\varepsilon}}\int_{0}^{\text{arcsinh}\left(2R\right)}\sinh\left(y\right)^{\varepsilon}dy<\frac{1}{2^{\varepsilon}}\int_{0}^{\text{arcsinh}\left(2R\right)}e^{\varepsilon y}dy.$$ Now, recalling that $$\text{arcsinh}\left(2t\right)=\log\left(\sqrt{4t^{2}+1}+2t\right)$$ we get $$\int_{0}^{R}\frac{t^{\varepsilon}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^{2}}}dt=O_{\varepsilon}\left(e^{\varepsilon\text{arcsinh}\left(2R\right)}\right)=O_{\varepsilon}\left(\left[\sqrt{4R^{2}+1}+2R\right]^{\varepsilon}\right)=O_{\varepsilon}\left(R^{\varepsilon}\right).$$ If we assume that when $t$ is negative we are working with complex numbers, we can essentially repeat the same argument in the range $(-R,0)$.